# not getting values to the spinner and getting Cannot find a value for null

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-spinner

I created a converter of few units. I used spinners to choose the units to convert but in my set adapter method when I set both from and to details its not taking if Placing only to from its working it not taking the exact value and showing blank I don't understand where the bug is. can anyone please help. it taking lots of time.

Uniqcon:

```
public class UniqueConverter extends Fragment {

    private Spinner fromDetails, toDetails;
    private EditText fromInput, toInput;




    public static UniqueConverter setArguments(int position) {
        UniqueConverter uniqueConverter = new UniqueConverter();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("position", position);
        uniqueConverter.setArguments(args);
        return uniqueConverter;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_uniquelayout, container, false);



        fromInput.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                Double inp;
                double out = 0;

                if (!fromInput.getText().toString().equals(""))
                {
                    String ifrom = (String) fromDetails.getSelectedItem();
                    String rto = (String) toDetails.getSelectedItem();
                    inp = Double.valueOf(fromInput.getText().toString());
                    int position = getArguments().getInt("position");
                    switch (position)
                    {
                        case 0:
                            setAdapter(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.temperatureform), "Celsius", "Fahrenheit");
                            TemperatureConverter con = new TemperatureConverter();
                            TemperatureConverter.Units fromUnit = TemperatureConverter.Units.fromString(ifrom);
                            TemperatureConverter.Units toUnit = TemperatureConverter.Units.fromString(rto);
                            out = con.TemperatureConvert(fromUnit,toUnit,inp);
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            setAdapter(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.weightform), "Kilograms", "Grams");
                            WeightConverter converter = new WeightConverter();
                            WeightConverter.Inus fromInus = WeightConverter.Inus.fromString(ifrom);
                            WeightConverter.Inus toInus = WeightConverter.Inus.fromString(rto);
                            out = converter.WeightConvert(fromInus,toInus,inp);
                            break;
}

                    toInput.setText(String.valueOf(out));

                }else {
                    toInput.setText("");
                }
            }
        });


        onInitVies(view);


        return view;
    }

    private void setAdapter(String[] spinnerItems, String fromDefaultText, String toDefaultText) {
        fromDetails.setAdapter(new CustomSpinnerAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.spinner_item, spinnerItems, fromDefaultText));
        toDetails.setAdapter(new CustomSpinnerAdapter(getContext(),R.layout.spinner_item,spinnerItems,toDefaultText));
    }

    private void onInitVies(View view) {
        fromDetails = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.fromSpinner);
        toDetails = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.toSpinner);

        fromInput = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.fromInput);
        toInput = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.toInput);
    }
```

String-array:

```
<string-array name="temperatureform">
        <item name="c">Celsius</item>
        <item name="f">Fahrenheit</item>
        <item name="k">Kelvin</item>
</string-array>

 <string-array name="weightform">
        <item name="kg">Kilograms</item>
        <item name="g">Grams</item>
        <item name="lb">Pounds</item>
</string-array>
```

logcat:

```
Exception dispatching finished signal.
03-15 02:40:25.843 14349-14349/com.cloudicalabs.converters E/MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
03-15 02:40:25.844 14349-14349/com.cloudicalabs.converters E/MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find a value for null
03-15 02:40:25.844 14349-14349/com.cloudicalabs.converters E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at com.cloudicalabs.converters.datahandlers.WeightConverter$Inus.fromString(WeightConverter.java:26)
03-15 02:40:25.844 14349-14349/com.cloudicalabs.converters E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at com.cloudicalabs.converters.fragments.UniqueConverter$1.afterTextChanged(UniqueConverter.java:95)
03-15 02:40:25.844 14349-14349/com.cloudicalabs.converters E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:8007)
03-15 02:40:25.844 14349-14349/com.cloudicalabs.converters E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.afterTextChanged(TextView.java:10168)
03-15 02:40:25.844 14349-14349/com.cloudicalabs.converters E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendAfterTextChanged(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1043)
03-15 02:40:25.844 14349-14349/com.cloudicalabs.converters E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:560)
03-15 02:40:25.844 14349-14349/com.cloudicalabs.converters E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:492)
03-15 02:40:25.844 14349-14349/com.cloudicalabs.converters E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:491)
03-15 02:40:25.844 14349-14349/com.cloudicalabs.converters E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.text.method.NumberKeyListener.onKeyDown(NumberKeyListener.java:121)
03-15 02:40:25.844 14349-14349/com.cloudicalabs.converters E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.widget.TextView.doKeyDown(TextView.java:6098)
03-15 02:40:25.844 14349-14349/com.cloudicalabs.converters E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.widget.TextView.onKeyDown(TextView.java:5911)
03-15 02:40:25.844 14349-14349/com.cloudicalabs.converters E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2640)
03-15 02:40:25.844 14349-14349/com.cloudicalabs.converters E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:9234)
03-15 02:40:25.844 14349-14349/com.cloudicalabs.converters E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1640)
03-15 02:40:25.844 14349-14349/com.cloudicalabs.converters E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1640)
03-15 02:40:25.844 14349-14349/com.cloudicalabs.converters E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1640)
03-15 02:40:25.844 14349-14349/com.cloudicalabs.converters E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1640)
03-15 02:40:25.844 14349-14349/com.cloudicalabs.converters E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1640)
03-15 02:40:25.844 14349-14349/com.cloudicalabs.converters E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1640)
03-15 02:40:25.844 14349-14349/com.cloudicalabs.converters E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1640)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello dear Try This this Don't use Direct

```
String[] temperatureform,weightform ;
temperatureform =getResources().getStringArray(R.array.weightform);
weightform=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.weightform);
 setAdapter(temperatureform,"Celsius", "Fahrenheit");
 setAdapter(weightform ,"Celsius", "Fahrenheit");
```

Comment: is it possible to add multiple array at once, how to set them to my setAdapter